# Run OMNeT++ simulation from terminal using Qtenv

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm using Veins (v5.1) along with SUMO (v0.32) and OMNeT++ (v5.6.2) in Linux Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to run the Qtenv from the terminal with the opp_run command. When the simulation window opens I still need to click run (F5) in order to start the simulation. Is there any way to start the simulation directly while using the Qtenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qtenv there is no way to start simulation automatically after opening the window.

**EDIT**

However, based on [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-gui-program) you may try use `xdotool` to start simulation by sending F5, for example:

```
xdotool search --name Qtenv windowactivate --sync %1 key F5 windowactivate `xdotool getactivewindow`
```

where `Qtenv` is a part of the title of window with your simulation.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to focus to the open window and then execute commands from terminal?

Comment: I have added a solution to send a key stroke to the window from console. Could you try it?

Comment: Thanks! I found the same solution and it works!